# White Screen in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in `Laravel 5.5` and I added some route to `web.php`.

It shows a white page on starting.

I clear the view, cache, and route also I try `composer dump-autoload` it is not working. If I set `debug` to `true` I get the same result.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was I define some wildcard route on the top, I move them to the end of the file and clear cache and route and its work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a route and access it by the URL, by default the `view.blade.php` will be empty.

Fill it with content and then it will show up!

Comment: I already have the content its there but its showing white screen

Comment: Check permissions (specially "storage" directory). Also try to send an output from controller (some string, just for test purpose).

Comment: I am in Windows environment  @RouhollahMazarei all permissions is given